# how to remove googlemymap water mark from iframe in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Iam new to reactjs,i want hide the googlemymap watermark....please let me know how to achieve this

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/embed?mid=1OMSkPKZi-U-CnmBr71zByNxp8HYi-vOc&ehbc=2E312F" frameborder="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%"  aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0" style={{position:'relative',border:'none',top:'-60px'}}  ></iframe>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by CSS

```
   <div style={{ width: "70%", height: "450px", overflow: "hidden" }}>
    <iframe
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1O7JsVqXNM97pPIat8PuIIt6JrZXUQJro&ehbc=2E312F"
      width="100%"
      height="900"
      frameborder="0"
      style={{ border: 0, marginTop: "-67px" }}
    ></iframe>
  </div>
```